# to hide a div on the button click of a parent div

Tags: jquery

I have an eligibilty form in which the user has to answer seven questions to  proceed to the next level.For submitting the answer I have provided "Yes & No" buttons.On clicking the "yes" button I have to hide that div and show an error message.But when the "yes" button of the first question is clicked i need only to show the error message only.If clicked "No" button next question is shown.Whenever "Yes" button is clicked i show error message.Think that after clicking "no" button and the next question is shown, I clicked the "yes" button.In that case I need to hide the showed question and show an error message.since the code is big i am putting it js fiddle.please me to solve this problem since i am new to jquery.

`please have a look at` https://jsfiddle.net/apv183t5/

my code:

```
$(function(){
            $(".yesBtn").click(function(){
                $(this).addClass("dangerBtn");
                $('.noBtn').removeClass("successBtn");
                /*$("#quesTwo").hide();*/
                $(this).closest('div>.divHide').hide();
                $(".errMsgDiv").show(500,function(){
                    $(".yesBtn").addClass("yesBtn");
                    $(".quesSec").css({"margin-bottom":"5px"});
                });
            }); 

            $("#first_no").click(function(){
                $(this).addClass("successBtn");
                $('.yesBtn').removeClass("dangerBtn");  
                $("#quesTwo").show(500);
                $(".errMsgDiv").hide(500,function(){
                    $(".quesSec").css({"margin-bottom":"30px"});
                });

            }); 
            $("#sec_no").click(function(){
                $(this).addClass("successBtn");
                $('.yesBtn').removeClass("dangerBtn");  ;
                $("#quesThree").show(500);
                $(".errMsgDiv").hide(500,function(){
                    $(".quesSec").css({"margin-bottom":"30px"});
                });         
            }); 
            $("#third_no").click(function(){
                $(this).addClass("successBtn");
                $('.yesBtn').removeClass("dangerBtn");  
                $("#quesFour").show(500);
                $(".errMsgDiv").hide(500,function(){
                    $(".quesSec").css({"margin-bottom":"30px"});
                });
            }); 
            $("#fourth_no").click(function(){
                $(this).addClass("successBtn");
                $('.yesBtn').removeClass("dangerBtn");  
                $("#quesFive").show(500);
                $(".errMsgDiv").hide(500,function(){
                    $(".quesSec").css({"margin-bottom":"30px"});
                });
            }); 
            $("#fifth_no").click(function(){
                $(this).addClass("successBtn");
                $('.yesBtn').removeClass("dangerBtn");  
                $("#quesSix").show(500);
                $(".errMsgDiv").hide(500,function(){
                    $(".quesSec").css({"margin-bottom":"30px"});
                });
            });
            $("#sixth_no").click(function(){
                $(this).addClass("successBtn");
                $('.yesBtn').removeClass("dangerBtn");  
                $("#quesSeven").show(500);
                $(".errMsgDiv").hide(500,function(){
                    $(".quesSec").css({"margin-bottom":"30px"});
                });
            });
            $("#seventh_no").click(function(){
                $(this).addClass("successBtn");
                $('.yesBtn').removeClass("dangerBtn");  
                $(".successMsgDiv").show(500,function(){
                    $(".quesSec").css({"margin-bottom":"30px"});
                $(".errMsgDiv").hide(500);
                });
            }); 
        });

<div class="col-sm-push-2 col-sm-8 quesSec">     
               <div class="shipping-info questionDiv">

                  <!-- Question 1 -->
                  <div class="col-xs-12" id="quesOne">
                       <h5>QUESTION <span class="quesNum">1 of 7</span></h5>
                       <ul class="star">
                          <li>
                            Is the Applicant or any Proposed Covered Person eligible for Medicaid or Medicare?
                          </li>
                       </ul>
                       <div class="col-md-3">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success yesBtn">YES</button>
                       </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                         <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger noBtn" id="first_no">NO</button>
                       </div>
                  </div> 

                 <!-- Question 1 Ends-->  

                 <!-- Question 2 --> 
                   <div class="col-xs-12 divHide" id="quesTwo">
                       <h5>QUESTION <span class="quesNum">2 of 7</span></h5>
                       <ul class="star">
                          <li>
                          Will any applicant have other health insurance in force on the policy effective date or be eligible for Medicaid?
                          </li>
                       </ul>
                       <div class="col-md-3">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success yesBtn">YES</button>
                       </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                         <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger noBtn" id="sec_no">NO</button>
                       </div>
                  </div> 
                 <!-- Question 2 Ends-->

                 <!-- Question 3 --> 
                   <div class="col-xs-12 divHide" id="quesThree">
                       <h5>QUESTION <span class="quesNum">3 of 7</span></h5>
                       <ul class="star">
                          <li>
                            Have/Are you, or any applicant:
                              <ul>
                                 <li>Now pregnant, in process of adoption or undergoing infertility treatment?</li>
                                 <li>Over 300 pounds if male or over 250 pounds if female?</li>
                                 <li>Been advised by a medical professional to have diagnostic testing, treatment, surgery that has not yet been completed?</li>
                              </ul>
                          </li>
                       </ul>
                       <div class="col-md-3">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success yesBtn">YES</button>
                       </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                         <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger noBtn" id="third_no">NO</button>
                       </div>
                  </div> 
                 <!-- Question 3 Ends-->

                 <!-- Question 4 --> 
                   <div class="col-xs-12 divHide" id="quesFour">
                       <h5>QUESTION <span class="quesNum">4 of 7</span></h5>
                       <ul class="star">
                          <li>
                            Within the last 5 years has any applicant had a diagnosis, symptoms, an abnormal test result or received treatment, medication or consultation for:
                              <ul>
                                 <li>cancer or malignant melanoma</li>
                                 <li>atrial fibrillation or abnormal heart rhythm, heart disorders, angina, heart attack or heart failure</li>
                                 <li>stroke</li>
                                 <li>uncontrolled hypertension</li>
                                 <li>diabetes except gestational</li>
                                 <li>hepatitis C or liver or kidney disorders</li>
                              </ul>
                          </li>
                       </ul>
                       <div class="col-md-3">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success yesBtn" >YES</button>
                       </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                         <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger noBtn" id="fourth_no">NO</button>
                       </div>
                  </div> 
                 <!-- Question 4 Ends-->

                 <!-- Question 5 --> 
                  <div class="col-xs-12 divHide" id="quesFive">
                       <h5>QUESTION <span class="quesNum">5 of 7</span></h5>
                       <ul class="star">
                          <li>
                            Within the last 5 years has any applicant been diagnosed or treated by a physician or medical practitioner for Acquired Immune Deficiency Syndrome (AIDS) or tested positive for Human Immunodeficiency Virus (HIV)?
                          </li>
                       </ul>
                       <div class="col-md-3">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success yesBtn">YES</button>
                       </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                         <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger noBtn" id="fifth_no">NO</button>
                       </div>
                  </div> 
                 <!-- Question 5 Ends-->

                 <!-- Question 6 --> 
                 <div class="col-xs-12 divHide" id="quesSix">
                       <h5>QUESTION <span class="quesNum">6 of 7</span></h5>
                       <ul class="star">
                          <li>
                            Is the Applicant or any Proposed Covered Person eligible for Medicaid or Medicare?
                          </li>
                       </ul>
                       <div class="col-md-3">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success yesBtn">YES</button>
                       </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                         <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger noBtn" id="sixth_no">NO</button>
                       </div>
                  </div> 
                 <!-- Question 6 Ends-->

                 <!-- Question 7 --> 
                  <div class="col-xs-12 divHide" id="quesSeven">
                       <h5>QUESTION <span class="quesNum">7 of 7</span></h5>
                       <ul class="star">
                          <li>
                            If all persons to be insured are United States citizens, please answer “No” to this question. If any person to be insured is not a United States citizen, has that person resided outside the United States at any time during the prior 12 months?
                          </li>
                       </ul>
                       <div class="col-md-3">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success yesBtn" id="Yesbtn">YES</button>
                       </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                         <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger noBtn" id="seventh_no">NO</button>
                       </div>
                  </div> 
                 <!-- Question 7 Ends-->  

               </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the required result

1. Have your "YES" and "NO" button in the same div element.
2. Find the closest ul and the parent div of the button. Then hide those elements.

Below are the modified code

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success yesBtn">YES</button>
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger noBtn" id="sec_no">NO</button>
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(".yesBtn").click(function(event){
    $(this).addClass("dangerBtn");                    
    $('.noBtn').removeClass("successBtn");

    $(this).closest('div>.divHide').find('ul').hide();
    $(this).closest('div').hide();

    $(".errMsgDiv").show(500,function(){
        $(".yesBtn").addClass("yesBtn");
        $(".quesSec").css({"margin-bottom":"5px"});
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for the help.When i tried this my no button is not working

Comment: I have forked and modified the code in JSFiddle. It seems to be working. Please take a look at the forked url https://jsfiddle.net/tor8kgu3/

Comment: thank for your help  sir.suppose that i clicked no on the second question then the third question appears.After third question appears i clicked yes button  of second   question then i want to hide second question and third question.can you help me with this.Again thank for your help sir